# Limit number of parallel running methods

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

In my class I have a download function. Now in order to not allow a too high number of concurrent downloads, I would like to block this function until a "download-spot" is free ;)

```
void Download(Uri uri)
{
    currentDownloads++;

    if (currentDownloads > MAX_DOWNLOADS)
    {
        //wait here
    }

    DoActualDownload(uri); // blocks long time

    currentDownloads--;
}
```

Is there a ready made programming pattern for this in C# / .NET?

edit: unfortunatelyt i cant use features from .net4.5 but only .net4.0

Comment: static variable to keep track of number of current downloads and make it thread safe

Comment: I don't see any parallel code. It's impossible to help if you don't show the actual code. There *are* constructs that will help but they depend on the API you use to perform the asynchronous action. For example, PLINQ and Dataflow have MaxDegreeOfParallelism options. Task.Run can be combined with a TaskScheduler that allows only a certain number of concurrent tasks

Comment: I'm assuming `Download` is an IO bound operation?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it downloads a file via http and then writes it to disk. so yes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this method can be called from many instances of this class. so there would be many downloads in paralell.

Comment: Can you install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`? Would help you here.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i guess i can.

Answer (score 3):

May be this

```
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
{        
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
};

Parallel.ForEach(downloadUri, parallelOptions, (uri, state, index) =>
{
    YourDownLoad(uri);
});
```

Comment: thanks! this sounds interesting! but in my case i want to make sure that the caller of YourDownload only continues once the call is actually finished.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **Semaphore** for this concurrency problem, see more in the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

For such cases, I create an own `Queue<MyQuery>` in a custom class like `QueryManager`, with some methods :

1. Each new query is enqueued in `Queue<MyQuery>` queries
2. After each "enqueue" AND in each query answer, I call `checkIfQueryCouldBeSent()`
3. The `checkIfQueryCouldBeSent()` method checks your conditions : number of concomitant queries, and so on. In your case you accept to launch a new query if global counter is less than 5. And you increment the counter
4. Decrement the counter in query answer

It works only if all your queries are asynchronous.
You have to store Callback in `MyQuery` class, and call it when query is over.

Comment: The .NET Framework already contains such a class, [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) with a MaxDegreeOfParallelism option

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for information, I read ActionBlock specifications. Nevertheless I think it is not adapted to asynchronous Action<T>, which must be able to notify the ActionBlock to continue with next action. In the case of asynchronous actions, it seems the whole ActionBlock would be finished immediatly.

Comment: ActionBlock is purpose-built for asynchronous processing - it's a descendant of the Robotics framework. If your method returns a Task, you can either `await` inside the block delegate or return the Task itself. There is an ActionBlock constructor that processes functions returning Task. You can also wait for the ActionBlock to finish processing by calling `block.Complete(); await block.Completion`;

Answer (score 1):

You're doing async IO bound work, there's no need to be using multiple threads with a call such as `Parallel.ForEach`.

You can simply use naturally async API's exposed in the BCL, such ones that make HTTP calls using `HttpClient`. Then, you can throttle your connections using `SemaphoreSlim` and it's `WaitAsync` method which asynchronously waits:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(3);
public async Task DownloadAsync(Uri uri)
{
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        string result = await DoActualDownloadAsync(uri);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

And your `DoActualyDownloadAsync` will use `HttpClient` to do it's work. Something along the lines of:

```
public Task<string> DoActualDownloadAsync(Uri uri)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    return httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
}
```